# How can I manage excessive hair shedding from dogs?

Tags: dogs, grooming, cleaning, shedding

Certain dogs have a reputation for shedding hair (Labradors, Golden Retrievers), creating a constant struggle to keep the house clean, especially as this shedding continues throughout the day. Shedding also increases at different stages of growth and seasonally.

Are there any methods to control hair shedding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can't control the shedding since it needs to happen.  The best preventative measure you can take is to brush/groom the dog regularly to ensure that the old hair is removed.

For dogs that get seasonal coats, it is important to groom them more frequently during the times their new coat is coming in.  For dogs that continually shed (like your retrievers), it is an on-going thing.

However, if you think your dog is shedding more than he should, examining his diet might be helpful as high quality food are important for a health coat.  His regular food should consist of high quality proteins.

Additionally, you can try to supplement his diet with a fatty acid supplement.  They sell DHA pills for dogs, but my vet also suggested just giving him human DHA pills (which are cheaper) and just cutting the dosage.  We just cut open the gel caps and squeeze a little on his food for meal times.  But before you start giving him supplements because you *think* something is wrong, it is recommended you have a vet check him out first.

And if it is just a matter of keeping the clean house, covering the furniture is the only remedy there.